# why does TypeScript's method need a variable as return type?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to typescript, forgive me if the question is stupid.

For the following code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
//....
export class MyApp {

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
//....
```

I understand that Nav is the return type, but what does "nav: Nav" means? why does a return type need a "nav" as a variable? I tried to look at the official document but didn't find a clue(perhaps I barked up to the wrong trees)
does this equivalent to:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
//....
export class MyApp {

  @ViewChild(nav: Nav) Nav;
//....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually looks like a property (not a method) of the class called `nav`, of type `Nav`, which is decorated by `ViewChild`. Putting in on one line makes it a little confusing I think. It's easier to see what its doing this way:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
//....
export class MyApp {

  @ViewChild(Nav)
  nav: Nav;
//....
```

You can read about decorators [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html). You can decorate classes, properties, or methods, and decorators use the `@decoratorName` syntax, much like they do in other languages.

EDIT:

To be a little clearer, in this case `ViewChild` is a *decorator factory*, bascially a function that returns a decorator. So you give this function `Nav` as an argument (which means that `Nav` is a class constructor function, I presume), and it returns the actual decorator.

Comment: wow. Thank you for letting me know I did bark up on the wrong tree.